# Admob ads not showing in a unity game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

So I have build a simple game using unity and I wanted to publish it on play store and for that I build an app bundle to publish on play store but the ads are not showing when I downloaded the game on device, though the ads were showing when I tested it on mobile using unity remote and even when I first build an apk to test on my device, the ads were running perfectly. But after I change some player settings, then the ads stopped showing. I'm absolutely clueless what's might be the reason because I'm not getting any kind of error, neither on admob dashboard nor in unity.

Can someone guide me, it's my first time interaction with admob ads.